# How to merge 3 columns into 1 new column with pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with "year", "month" and "day" columns, i want to merge them together into one new column seperated by a "," or a "/". And finally take the final date obtained and transform it to a day of the week like this : (31/01/2020 ==> Friday)
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
df['weekday']=df['month']+'/'+df['day']+'/'+df['year']
df['weekday']=pd.to_datetime(df['weekday'])
df['weekday']=df.weekday.dt.weekday()
```

Mileage may vary depending on dtype of year, month, day columns. Recommend casting to a string with [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) if not already.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
df['weekday']=df['month'].astype(str)+'/'+df['day'].astype(str)+'/'+df['year'].astype(str)

df['weekday']=pd.to_datetime(df['weekday'])

df['weekday']=df.weekday.dt.weekday()
```